# Why use is_safe?

Tags: python, django

I'm reading Django documentation on custom filter.

and.. I don't see the reason of the existence of is_safe.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping

when I coded some examples and then tried them, the result were always same whether is_safe is True or False.

**Why do you use is_safe?**

Here is my code

## extra_tags.py

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django import template
import datetime
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='custom_lower')        
@stringfilter
def lower(value):
    is_safe = True
    return '%sxx'%value
lower.is_safe = True;

from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@register.filter(name='custom_lf')
def initial_letter_filter(text, autoescape=None):
    first, other = text[0], text[1:]
    if autoescape:
        esc = conditional_escape
    else:
        esc = lambda x: x
    result = '<strong>%s</strong>%s' % (esc(first), esc(other))
    return mark_safe(result)
initial_letter_filter.is_safe = False
initial_letter_filter.needs_autoescape = True
```

my point is that whether I code is_safe=True or is_safe=False, the result will be auto-escaped characters.. and I don't see why we use is_safe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `is_safe` together with `mark_safe()` is redundant, which is probably why you don't see any differences.

As noted in the section you linked to, down where it talks about `mark_safe()`:

> There's no need to worry about the is_safe attribute in this case (although including it wouldn't hurt anything). Whenever you manually handle the auto-escaping issues and return a safe string, the is_safe attribute won't change anything either way.

`is_safe` is simply a way to automatically mark the return value of a function as safe, *given that all of the external inputs were already safe*. Django will still autoescape anything that was an input, but it won't try to escape the other parts which were added afterwards by your function.

`mark_safe()`, on the other hand, certifies that the output is safe regardless of whether the inputs were safe - it's a much stronger requirement that you have to fulfill if you're going to use it.

Comment: You may want to expand on when it would be useful

Comment: Edited to be a bit more specific.

Comment: The less confusing answer is that the use of is_safe has been deprecated and removed in Django 1.6. You can either use mark_safe() to wrap your return text, or use @register.filter(is_safe=True) and let the filter wrap it for you.